# How to load executable configuration which is spread across multiple config files?

Tags: c#, reflection, app-config, configurationmanager, system.reflection

I have a Windows application called `TechReader`. Its configuration file is `TechReader.exe.config`. Some parts of the configuration are kept in other configuration files. So I refer to that config file from the config section created in the exe.config.

```
 <TechReader.ProviderConfiguration file="localProvider.config"/>
```

Now I want to load the whole configuration of my application using reflection. I use code like this.

```
Assembly techReaderAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TechReaderStarter));
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(techReaderAssembly .Location);
```

`TechReaderStarter` class is defined in the project whose output is windows application and not the library.

When I use above code, I get `TargetInvocationException` and `ConfigurationErrorsException`

1. Is the approach correct?
2. Will `OpenExeConfiguration` load the final configuration generated by merging the exe.config and other referenced config file?
3. How can I achieve the things?

Note: I want to use this Windows application to install as a Windows Service. I am trying to read the configuration in the `ServiceInstaller` class (a class which inherits `ServiceInstaller`) so that the details like service name mentioned in the configuration of the Service will be available to the `installutil`. For this I have to use reflection to get the exact configuration of the service.